# How do I check the actual format of an image file?

Tags: filesystems

I have a bunch of image files with the extension ".png", but I'm fairly sure some of them are actually JPEGs that were renamed to PNGs. As far as I know, simply renaming the file doesn't actually change the formatting, compression, etc., so how do I check which are formatted accordingly to their extensions?

Plus, does XnConvert actually convert the images' format?

Comment: Renaming a file/changing its extension is sort of like changing the label on the sugar container to "Salt". It has no effect on the contents but annoys the humans who have to use it. Try adding a .JPG extension to one of your PNG files (ie, change MYFILE.PNG to MYFILE.PNG.JPG or just MYFILE.JPG) to see if programs will open it. Or open the file in a text editor. If JPG, its first four charactes should be ÿØÿà. If PNG, the first four characters will be ‰PNG

Answer (score 14):

If you have either a Linux system, or [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) (on Windows) you could type

```
file myimagewithoutextension
```

Output:

```
myimagewithoutextension: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 96x96, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 768x576, frames 3
```

The `file` command completely ignores the file extension, but rather relies on information in the file header.

Alternatively, open the suspected PNG in Notepad. If it's truly a PNG, it will have `‰PNG` on the first line. Jpeg's will have `JFIF` somewhere near the start.

[image]

Comment: I believe `file` is also available in [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/install.html) (https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Ffile%2Ffile-5.32-1&grep=file) and there is also an (old) [version for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) at GnuWin32

Comment: `file` is also available if you're using Git Bash

Answer (score 5):

> How do I check which are formatted accordingly to their extensions?

You can use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) for this. ImageMagick is available for [Windows, Mac and Linux](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php). You will typically want one of the "DLL" versions for Windows (not one of the "Static" versions).

Once installed, you can identify images with incorrect extensions with ex. `magick identify file.ext`:

*Example*

```
# Should be a .jpg, not a .png

magick identify it-kama-sutra.png
it-kama-sutra.png JPEG 500x397 500x397+0+0 8-bit sRGB 37707B 0.000u 0:00.060

# Should be a .gif, not a .png

magick identify giphy.png
giphy.png[0] GIF 346x255 346x255+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 0.000u 0:00.062
giphy.png[1] GIF 346x255 346x255+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 0.000u 0:00.087
giphy.png[2] GIF 346x255 346x255+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 0.000u 0:00.092
[...]
giphy.png[13] GIF 346x255 346x255+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 0.000u 0:00.237
giphy.png[14] GIF 346x255 346x255+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 0.000u 0:00.329
giphy.png[15] GIF 346x255 346x255+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 716527B 0.000u 0:00.336
```

Note that on Windows, you need to add `magick.exe` (`magick`) to your Windows path to use it without specifying its exact location (ex. `C:\path\to\imagemagick\magick.exe`).